# Convertir botocore.response.StreamingBody a JSON y descargarlo en AJAX

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, amazon-s3

Me gustaría solicitar mediante un frontend, con una petición en AJAX, a un backend hecho en Django, una solicitud de una imagen S3 utilizando `boto3.client`.

```
s3_response_object=s3.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME,Key=BUCKET_FILE_NAME)
object_content = s3_response_object['Body'].read()
```

Pero el problema es que `s3_response_object['Body']` me devuelve: `<botocore.response.StreamingBod...>`, y cuando lo paso a JSON, o bien me lo devuelve a `null` si intento convertir la respuesta entera:

```
response_data = json.dumps(s3_response_object, default = myconverter)
mimetype = 'application/json'
return HttpResponse(response_data, mimetype)
```

O bien me da error si intento convertir el Body nada más

```
data = json.loads(object_content)
response_data = json.dumps({ 'res': data })
mimetype = 'application/json'
return HttpResponse(response_data, mimetype)
```

Error

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Y después en el AJAX, lo tendría que descargar automáticamente:

```
   success: function (data, textStatus) {

      var blob = new Blob([data]);
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const link=document.createElement('a');
      link.href= url;
      link.setAttribute('download','image.png');
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();

  },
```

**Edito:**

He conseguido enviar el archivo codificado con en el objeto

```
s3_response_object['Body'] = s3_response_object['Body'].read().decode("ISO-8859-1")
```

Pero no consigo que AJAX lo descargue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respecto al back-end, puedes crear la siguiente **vista** en el archivo `views.py` de tu *aplicación* de Django.

```py
import io

from django.http import FileResponse
import boto3


def get_image(request):
    # Sesión de S3 (debe estar configurada)
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")

    # Datos del objeto/archivo de S3
    bucket = "bucket_example"
    key = "image_example.png"

    # Obtenemos el archivo de S3 como bytes
    img = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)["Body"].read()

    # Creamos un buffer de bytes
    buf = io.BytesIO(img)

    # Devolvemos el archivo
    return FileResponse(buf, as_attachment=True, filename=key)
```

La vista `get_image` devuelve la imagen que está en S3 como un archivo adjunto.

Respecto al front-end, en tu **plantilla** (*template*) de HTML, dentro de la función de JavaScript de éxito de Ajax, puedes escribir lo siguiente:

```js
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = "{% url 'get_image_url' %}";

document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

Donde `get_image_url` es el identificador/nombre de la URL correspondiente a la vista `get_image`. Este identificador está definido en el archivo `urls.py` de tu *aplicación* de Django.

Comment: Gracias, lo había solucionado ya, muy muy parecido a como indicas tu.

Comment: De nada. De acuerdo, perfecto.